# Passing Component to another Component through property object (for ng-bootstrap modal)

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, angular9

I have started learning angular 9 recently.

I have to display a modal with dynamic content. I'm trying to build a generic modal that can show content based on values it receives through a service. I am using ng-bootstrap modal for the same.

I am trying to display modal bypassing components as a parameter to modal service (As specified here - https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples#component)

Here is what I have done so far:

**This is the Component I want to show in modal**

```js
    //some imports...
    import { UploadMediaComponent } from '../upload-media/upload-media.component'; // Component I want to display in modal.

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-images',
      templateUrl: './images.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./images.component.css']
    })
    export class ImagesComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    modal: IModal = {} as any;

    constructor(private httpService: HttpService, private commonService: CommonService, private modalService: ModalService) { }

    // some code here ...
    addImage() {
        this.modal.title = "Add New Image";
        this.modal.component = UploadMediaComponent; // Assigning UploadMediaComponent to a modal interface object.
        this.modalService.showModal(this.modal);
      }

    // some other code
```

**Modal Component that displays the modal**

```js
    import { IModal } from '../modal-interface';
    import { ModalService } from '../service/modal.service';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-modal',
      templateUrl: './modal.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./modal.component.css'],
    })
    export class ModalComponent implements OnInit {

      modal: IModal;

      constructor(config: NgbModalConfig, private modalService: NgbModal, private modalAppService: ModalService) { 
      //some default modal config options and getting modal options from modalAppService
      openModal();

     }

      ngOnInit(): void { }

      @ViewChild('content') content: ElementRef;

      //this method is called to open modal window
      openModal() {
        if (this.modal.component) {
          let modalInstance = this.modalService.open(this.modal.component, { size: 'lg' }); // this opens modal with UploadMediaComponent specified above.
          modalInstance.componentInstance.title = this.modal.title;
        }
        else {
          this.modalService.open(this.content, { size: 'lg' });
        }
      }
```

**This code works fine.** The modal is displayed as intended. Everything works fine.

My question is - Is this the correct way to achieve this? I'm not sure if passing Component reference through Interface object is the right way. If not, is there any other way to achieve the same?

Thank you.

Comment: Anyone who could help?

Comment: I don't see `IModal` interface and the method `showModal ` in the current version of ng-bootstrap. which version are you using?

Comment: overall looks good (: just doesn't much with ng-bootstrap API